# why is readfile necessary after a flush

Tags: php, buffer, readfile, flush

So i'm using a solution i found on internet to send file, and it's actually working !
But i don't really understand why :(

In my solution i'm generating a CSV (test;test;test;test;test).

So i tell my header it's a csv file and that it should be an attachment as well :

```
<?php
$nom = time().'.csv';
header('Content-type: text/csv');
header('Content-disposition: attachment;filename='.$nom);
?>
```

I understand this, this is simple, but when it comes to :

```
flush();
readfile($nom);
```

i understand that flush(); is devlivering the buffer to the client right ?
But why is readfile(); necessary ?
I mean, if content is sent, why would i read the file again ?

Comment: `flush()` has nothing to do with sending the file contents, it just flushes anything you've already echoed.

Comment: In this case `flush()` sends the headers you specified as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readfile($nom);` is actually reading your file and echoing it, so the client CAN receive the data. Without that, the csv output would be empty.

`flush()` just ensures the output buffer is emptied, before the writing of output starts. I think its not even required at this point. It just makes sure, that the output buffer you are writing to with `readfile` is empty when doing so.